# ie11 css rotate - background element not clickable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

I'm creating a tab interface whereby the active tab has a rotate transformation which allows a preview of the next tab to be visible. Clicking on a button in the preview area will open the next tab.

This is working fine in all browsers apart from IE11. See snippet below.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('button').click(function() {
    alert('Button was clicked');
  });
})
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}

.container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container .tab {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 185%;
  height: 140%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(-25deg);
  transform-origin: 50% 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container .tab .content {
  transform: rotate(25deg);
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  margin-left: 50%;
  position: relative;
  height: 75%;
  width: 55%;
}

.container .tab-1 {
  z-index: 2;
}

.container .tab-1 .content {
  background-color: red;
}

.container .tab-2 {
  z-index: 1;
  height: 200%;
}

.container .tab-2 .content {
  background-color: green;
}

.container .tab-2 button {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 37%;
  right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="tab tab-1">
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="tab tab-2">
    <div class="content">
      <button type="button">
        Click me
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I think the problem is that although IE visibly performs the rotation, the original bounding area itself is not rotated, thus the click doesn't get applied on the background element.

Anybody got any ideas how I can fix this? jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/bmq2e2ae/1/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For this to work in IE you can add `pointer-events: none` for `.tab .content` and bring back `pointer-events` to initial state for children of `.tab .content`.

Demo:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('button').click(function() {
    alert('Button was clicked');
  });
})
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}

.container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container .tab {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 185%;
  height: 140%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(-25deg);
  transform-origin: 50% 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container .tab .content {
  transform: rotate(25deg);
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  margin-left: 50%;
  position: relative;
  height: 75%;
  width: 55%;
}

.container .tab-1 {
  z-index: 2;
}

.container .tab-1 .content {
  background-color: red;
}

.container .tab-2 {
  z-index: 1;
  height: 200%;
}

.container .tab-2 .content {
  background-color: green;
}

.container .tab-2 button {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 37%;
  right: 20px;
}

/* IE Hack: disable pointer-events */
.container .tab .content {
  pointer-events: none;
}

/* IE Hack: enable pointer-events for descendants */
.container .tab .content > * {
  pointer-events: initial;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="tab tab-1">
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="tab tab-2">
    <div class="content">
      <button type="button">
        Click me
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Also you wrap this hack in media query browser hack to be evaluated only in IE

```
@media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active), (-ms-high-contrast: none) { 
  /* IE Hack: disable pointer-events */
  .container .tab .content {
    pointer-events: none;
  }

  /* IE Hack: enable pointer-events for descendants */
  .container .tab .content > * {
    pointer-events: initial;
  }
}
```

Comment: Good idea. Does this mean nothing in the active tab can be clicked? E.g. hyperlinks? Can we override pointer-events property for any hyperlinks?

Comment: @GSTAR Updated answer to work even if you want to add buttons on active tab.

Comment: @GSTAR Also you can apply this IE hacky styles only for active tab, not for every. Depends only your requirements.

Comment: Amazing. This looks like the best solution so far. Thank you.

Comment: When I test it in IE11, I don't get the alert from the "Click me" button. Is something missing in the code snippet?

Comment: @ConnorsFan That's strange. I get "Click me" alert in IE11. And OP too.

Comment: I can select the "Click me" text but the button is not clickable in my IE11. Maybe `pointer-events: all` (instead of `pointer-events: initial`) would solve the problem?

Comment: @ConnorsFan Strange that it's not working in your IE11 and works in my IE. Does `pointer-events: all` work for you?

Comment: Yes, it works with `pointer-events: all`. I tested it with a copy of your code snippet. I don't know what special setting I have in my IE configuration, that makes it behave differently from yours...

Comment: @ConnorsFan,  Vadim: check my solution below, It will work in all browser.

Answer (score 3):

The parent element `.tab-2` of the button has a lower `z-index` set then the other `.tab-1`. So in IE `.tab-1` is covering everything, when trying to click even though not visibility.

Take the `button` element out of the `.tab-2 .content` elements and place after both inside the container. Then set `position:absolute` and a higher `z-index` then both the `.container .tab-2` and `.container .tab-1`. The re-position.

**Note:** You have to scroll in example below to see button due to elements height.

**[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/bmq2e2ae/5/)**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('button').click(function() {
    alert('Button was clicked');
  });
})
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}

.container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container .tab {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 185%;
  height: 140%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(-25deg);
  transform-origin: 50% 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container .tab .content {
  transform: rotate(25deg);
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  margin-left: 50%;
  position: relative;
  height: 75%;
  width: 55%;
}

.container .tab-1 {
  z-index: 2;
}

.container .tab-1 .content {
  background-color: red;
}

.container .tab-2 {
  z-index: 1;
  height: 200%;
}

.container .tab-2 .content {
  background-color: green;
}

.container button {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5%;
  right: 10px;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="tab tab-1">
    <div class="content">Tab 1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="tab tab-2">
    <div class="content">Tab 2</div>
  </div>
  <button type="button">Click me</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Good answer but I can't have the button outside of the tab.. I only used the button as a quick example, but in reality each tab will have its own button with its own style and text.

Comment: Thank you.. Just wondering is it's not possible to place the buttons for each tab after/before the actual tab element. Then give them different class names to style and position appropriately? For example .tab-2-button and .tab-1-button for class or id names.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of rotating the first tab, you could rotate the second one (the one with the button). It would allow to keep that second tab on top of the first one. You can see the result in [**this jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/ConnorsFan/49h8bsjt/).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('button').click(function(e) {
     e.stopPropagation();
        alert('Button was clicked');
    });
    $('.tab-1').click(function() {
        alert('Tab1 was clicked');
    });
    $('.tab-2').click(function() {
        alert('Tab2 was clicked');
    });
})
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0
}

.container {
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.container .tab {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.container .tab .content {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: red;
}

.container .tab-2 {
    transform: translateX(63%) translateY(100%) rotate(-25deg);
    transform-origin: 0% 0%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.container .tab-2 .content {
    background-color: green;
    transform: rotate(25deg) translateX(-63%) translateY(-100%);
    transform-origin: 0% 0%;
}

.container .tab-2 button {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 4%;
    right: 3%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="tab tab-1">
        <div class="content">
            Tab 1
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tab tab-2">
        <div class="content">
            Tab 2
            <button type="button">
                Click me
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

When you use CSS3 TRANSFORMS you need to use different tags for diffeent browser.

You need to use like mentioned below.

```
-webkit-transform: rotate(-25deg) translateX(-50%);
-webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
-moz-transform: rotate(-25deg) translateX(-50%);
-moz-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
-o-transform: rotate(-25deg) translateX(-50%);
-o-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
-ms-transform: rotate(-25deg) translateX(-50%);
-ms-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
transform: rotate(-25deg) translateX(-50%);
transform-origin: 50% 0%;
```

This will work and supported in below mentioned browser versions.

> Chrome : 4.0+
>
> Firefox : 3.5+
>
> Safari : 3.1+
>
> IE : 9.0+
>
> Opera : 10.5+

**1st Example from requirement** : Instead of rotating both the div you can rotate only second div and it will work. Please check below solution.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('button').click(function() {
        alert('Button was clicked');
    });
});
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0
}

.container {
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.container .tab {

    width: 185%;
    height: 140%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.container .tab .content {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.container .tab-1 {
    z-index: 2;
    width: 100%;
}

.container .tab-1 .content {
    background-color: red;
}

.container .tab-2 {
    z-index: 3;
    transform: translateX(-40%) rotate(-25deg);
    transform-origin: 50% 0;
}

.container .tab-2 .content {
    background-color: green;
}

.container .tab-2 button {
    position: absolute;
    right: 60px;
    top:20px;
    transform: translateX(50%) rotate(25deg);
    transform-origin: 50% 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="tab tab-1">
        <div class="content">

        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="tab tab-2">
        <div class="content">
            <button type="button">
                Click me
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**2nd Example from requirement.**: Within one div you can achieve this. Please check below.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('button').click(function() {
        alert('Button was clicked');
    });
});
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0
}

.container {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.container .tab{
    z-index: 2;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: red;
    overflow: hidden;
    
}

.container .content {
    z-index: 62;
    width: 200px;
    height: 120px;
    background-color: green;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -72px;
    right: -35px;
    transform: rotate(-25deg) ;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-25deg) ;
    -moz-transform: rotate(-25deg) ;
    -o-transform: rotate(-25deg) ;
    -ms-transform: rotate(-25deg) ;
}
.container button{
  border:1px solid #eee;
}
.container a {
  color:#FFF;
}

.container button,
.container a {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    margin-right: 30px;
    right: 15px;
    bottom: 80px;
    transform: rotate(25deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(25deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(25deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(25deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(25deg);
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>IE10/11 Media Query Test</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div class="container">
          <div class="tab tab-1">
          Tab With Link 
              <div class="content">
                  <a  href="https://www.google.co.in">Link</a>
              </div>
          </div>

          <div class="tab tab-2">
          Tab With Button 
              <div class="content">
                  <button id="check_btn" type="button">Click me</button>
              </div>
          </div>

          <div class="tab tab-3">
          Tab Without Link or Button
              <div class="content">
              </div>
          </div>

          <div class="tab tab-4">
              Only Tab with no Green Area
          </div>
      </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

This will help you. Let me know if it not works for you.

Comment: Did you test this? It makes no difference. Also the transform property in IE11 doesn't need the vendor prefix.

Comment: @GSTAR: I changed CSS code, and its working perfect in IE as per your requirement. Please check and let me know.

Comment: @GSTAR : You are right that transform property in IE11 doesn't need the vendor prefix but that requires in Safari and other browsers.